# php include gives error

Tags: php, include

I am beginner in php, trying to make one main.php file that incldes header and footer for the start

#### header.php

```
<html>
<body>
<div class="header">
logo, navigation etc
</div>
```

#### footer.php

```
<div class="footer">
Footer content here
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

#### and the main file

```
<?php include "header.php"; ?>
<div class="main content">
<h1> header </h1>
<p> paragraph </p>
</div>
<?php include "footer.php"; ?>
```

#### the errors:

```
Warning: include(header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 1
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'header.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 1

Warning: include(footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in - on line 6
Warning: include(): Failed opening 'footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:') in - on line 6
```

all files are in the same foler and doing it on XAMPP

Comment: Which folder?  A folder whose parent is htdocs?

Comment: .. So your files are in htdocs?

Comment: Are you sure they are named correctly and that it's not 'header.php.html' or something?

Comment: it does seem weard that Coda asks for permission to work with php file, but i did check they all were header.php with noraml extension

Comment: Well, I wish I had a better answer for you, but I have been unable to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Any file you are including must be in your [include_path](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path).  Call [get_include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php) to see the current value.

Comment: The `include_path` already includes `.` (which is the current directory of the script) so the "No suck file" error is mysterious. My guess is an obscure permissions issue?

Comment: "which is the current directory of the script" - are you sure about that? try getcwd() first

Comment: I suppose it could be...you might have some weird umask and are creating files as not readable by all.

Answer (score 0):

you should add your files in the same folder so they'll be in the same parent directory then you can use "include" to access them directly ex: in folder called Home there are 2 php files if i create a third one i could use this code "<?php  include 'name of one the two other files found.php' hope its clear

Answer (score 0):

If header, footer and main files are in the same directory, try this:

```
include dirname(__FILE__) . '/header.php';
```